# Time series plotting on R grouped by ID

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, time-series

I have got the following dataframe:

```
Id    Price   Animals  X       Date
A     1       Dog      Kiwi    05/2020
B     1       Cat      NA      06/2020
B     3       Dog      NA      07/2020
A     4       Cat      Banana  08/2020
A     5       Mouse    Apple   01/2020
B     9       Cat      Melon   02/2020
C     0       Cat      NA      03/2020
C     4       Cat      NA      05/2020
```

On R, I am trying to plot *three* different time series plots of the Price column, grouped by the ID. I would like to show them on a unique graph afterwards. Is there any quick command to do so?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use facets in `ggplot2`. Note it's best to convert to actual dates first.

It's not clear whether a time series makes much sense here in view of the different animals, but I have added an optional line to show the animal type according to colored points. You could delete this line if it's not what you're looking for.

```r
df$Date <- as.Date(paste0("01/", df$Date), format = "%d/%m/%Y")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(Date, Price)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(Id~.) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(Id = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C"), 
    Price = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 9L, 0L, 4L), Animals = c("Dog", 
    "Cat", "Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Cat", "Cat", "Cat"), X = c("Kiwi", 
    NA, NA, "Banana", "Apple", "Melon", NA, NA), Date = c("05/2020", 
    "06/2020", "07/2020", "08/2020", "01/2020", "02/2020", "03/2020", 
    "05/2020")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df
#>   Id Price Animals      X    Date
#> 1  A     1     Dog   Kiwi 05/2020
#> 2  B     1     Cat   <NA> 06/2020
#> 3  B     3     Dog   <NA> 07/2020
#> 4  A     4     Cat Banana 08/2020
#> 5  A     5   Mouse  Apple 01/2020
#> 6  B     9     Cat  Melon 02/2020
#> 7  C     0     Cat   <NA> 03/2020
#> 8  C     4     Cat   <NA> 05/2020
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @Waie what do you want to do with the y axis?

Comment: Instead of having 0.0, 2.5, 5.0, 7.5; I just want 2.5 and 7.5 because in my plots the numbers overlap significantly.

Comment: @Waie add `+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(2.5, 7.5))` after `theme_bw()`